# Error in deleting row

Tags: php

Anyone know this problem i cant delete row in my table?

```
<?php $cus = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM priest") or die(mysql_error()); ?>

<?php WHILE($row = mysql_fetch_array($cus)){
  $id = $row['p_id'];
  $pid = $row['p_id'];
  $fname = $row['firstname'] . "&nbsp;" .$row['middlename']. "&nbsp;" . $row['lastname'];
}

?>

<tr class="gradeA del<?php echo $id;?>">
  <td><?php echo $pid; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $fname; ?></td>

  <td><a  href ='priest_list.php'>
      <img src='images/delete.png' title='Delete Priest' height='23'></a></td>
```

i add this in below the code :

and this is the code in my connect.php where my function is

```
<?php  
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

 if (!$conn)
{
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("rain_scheduling_system", $conn) or die('Could not Select: '.mysql_error());

function delete_priest($a)
{
  mysql_query("DELETE FROM priest WHERE p_id ='$a' ");
}
?>
```

Comment: {

                    delete_priest($_REQUEST['p_id']);

                    } why is this curly braces here?

Comment: i just try to re arrange it but i think i just post it like that... any comment about why my row is not deleting? or is there something wrong in code? tnx

Comment: First, get rid of the first `{` before `delete_priest($_REQUEST['p_id']);`

Comment: Your code doesn't make a lot of sense. You've started a `while` loop, apparently reading data from a query you haven't shown. Then, for no apparent reason, and while still in the loop, you seem to attempt to call `delete_priest()` in code that looks as though it should be in an `if` block, but isn't. You never actually close the `while` loop. I can't fathom this at all.

Comment: Where do you call the `delete_priest` function?

Comment: I noticed your edit. You removed your closing `}` for your `while` condition. Tell us, as Burhan asked, where/how you're calling the function. If you're not using it, then delete it. We're not going to sit around and magically make it work for you.

Comment: you should pass the id of the row you want to delete on the page where you call your delete function. Something like priest_list.php?id=$id

Comment: i just try separate the delete_priest into <?php inlcude('connect.php');$id = $_GET['p_id'];
                    {
                    delete_priest($_REQUEST['p_id']);
                    }
?> and add closing to my while } ... sorry if im kinda bad... im kinda new in php environment.. and still want to know more about it..

Comment: i put the code side the link line <a href='priest_list?id=$id'> but when i start to click delete it didnt call the delete function and the row is still not deleted...

Comment: The code you now have doesn't call the delete function at all. Rather than making haphazard, random edits, go away and do some proper study. Then rewrite your code and come back if you still have trouble.

Comment: btw. tnx for all the comments i just sovle my problem in deleting the row..... but i need to refresh again the page to see the row is deleted. i just add <?php echo "<td><a  href ='priest_list.php?id=$id'><img src='images/delete.png' title='Delete Priest' height='23'></a></td>" ?>